# Save Excel file in Visual studio

Tags: c#, excel, spire.xls

I've been trying to edit excel files and it works but I can't seem to save the changes I'm making. I've used interop, EPPLUS, Spire.xls and IRON.XL and the file just won't save. Thus I'm thinking that the problem lies with my environment but I don't know where to look.

```
public void AppendDataToExcelSheetSpireXls(string[,] data)
{
        Spire.Xls.Workbook wb = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
        wb.LoadFromFile("excel-testing.xls");
        bool check = wb.ReadOnly;
        Spire.Xls.Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets[0];
        sheet.Range["A1"].Text = "TOM";
        wb.Save();
}
```

(Readonly property is false by the way)

and when I'm printing the A column in console :

[image]

Yet after the program closes, it doesn't save the changes...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Tried running VS as administrator and it works fine now.